# Getting parent directory not working in windows 8 batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8

i have a folder structure as

```
c:\name\myname
```

I wrote a batch file

**test.bat**

```
@echo off  
echo %CD%  
echo %CD%\..  
set k=%CD%  
set c=%k%\..  
echo %k%  
echo %c%  
pause
```

**Output**

```
c:\name\myname  
c:\name\myname\\..  
c:\name\myname  
c:\name\myname\\..
```

**Expected Output**

```
c:\name\myname  
c:\name  
c:\name\myname  
c:\name
```

I have installed windows 8 OS. I want to get parent directory from current directory. May be i don't know the correct syntax to get parent directory.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623780/how-to-get-windows-batchs-parent-folder

Comment: suppose i have a structure like c:\user\myname\check\test, i need a path from this as c:\user\myname. How can i get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to obtain a reference to a file/folder: arguments to batch files and `for` command. This second option is what we will use here. As it is not clear what parent do you need, let's see how to obtain each

1 - Get parent of current active directory

```
for %%a in (..) do echo %%~fa
```

get a reference to the parent of the current active folder inside the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a` and once we have the reference, get the full path to it

2 - Get parent of the folder holding the batch file

```
for %%a in ("%~dp0.") do echo %%~dpa
```

same idea. `%0` is a reference to the current batch file, so `%~dp0` is the drive and path where the batch file is stored. This value ends in a backslash, so, to get a reference to the folder an aditional dot is added. Once we have the reference to the folder holding the batch file in `%%a`, `%%~dpa` will return the drive and path where the element referenced in `%%a` is stored. As `%%a` is the folder holding the batch file, `%%~dpa` is the parent, the folder where is stored the folder with the batch.

Comment: suppose i have a structure like c:\user\myname\check\test, i need a path from this as c:\user\myname. How can i get it?

Comment: @Kumar, `for %%a in ("c:\user\myname\check\test\..\..") do echo %%~fa`

Comment: @kumar, or in a relative way `for %a in (..\..) do echo %~fa`